# grub not loading with SHIFT after file modification

Tags: boot, grub2, resolution, grub-legacy

Attempt to overcome blackscreen I ran the following steps

- created file `/etc/grub.d/01_915resolution`
- wrote the following lines into the file

`echo insmod 915resolution
echo 915resolution 58 1366 768 32`

- then changed permission

`chmod +x /etc/grub.d/01_915resolution`

- Next I added resolution lines to the /etc/default/grub

`GRUB_GFXMODE = 1366 x 768 x 32
sudo update-grub`

I can now not get the Grub Menu when I hit shift.

How can I remove these changes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

- boot from a LiveCD, (or USB),
- delete the `01_915resolution` file
- open the `/media/ubuntu/ImpossibleLongNumber/etc/default/grub/` file in `gedit`
- remove the offending lines
- reboot

Comment: Hi, yeah just to add needed to mount the partition `sda6` and `update-grub`.  To update grub I need to also --bind /dev /sys /proc to the newly mounted drive.  Then need to be in `chroot` to run `update-grub`